# If Condition reading multiple items of an array in VBA

Tags: vba

```
For i = 2 To 7
If SlideSeen(i) = False Then GoTo EndSlide
Next i
```

How do I make the logic in such a manner that I can make an ***If Condition* reading multiple items of an array.**

In this case: `If SlideSeen(2) to SlideSeen(7) = false Then Goto EndSlide`

**EDIT: This code works:**

```
Dim allTrues As Boolean
allTrues = True

For i = 2 To 7
If SlideSeen(i) = False Then allTrues = False
Next

If allTrues = True Then
'
Else
'
End If
```

Comment: Apologies, I had posted the wrong iteration of the code in haste. I have corrected it now.

Comment: Yep that works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to check if any of those array elements are `True`... if not, all are `False`.

```
For i = 2 To 7
    Dim anyTrues As Boolean
    If slideSeen(i) Then anyTrues = True
Next

If Not anyTrues Then GoTo EndSlide
```

though I would caution against using `GoTo` here as that could be the start of spaghetti code.

Comment: Yes! This logic works. I customized it to fit my project. I'll make sure that it doesn't end up being an example of spaghetti code.